# Radius of convergence of function strictly greater than $1$ or not?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ with power series$$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n z^n.$$Let$$f_n(z) = a_0 + a_1z + \ldots + a_nz^n.$$Suppose that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on the closed unit disk. Is the radius of convergence strictly greater than $1$ or not?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Are you asking whether the sequence converges outside the unit disk?

Comment: Closely related: [condition for the radius of convergence of a power series to be greater than 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44558/condition-for-the-radius-of-convergence-of-a-power-series-to-be-greater-than-1)

Answer (score 1):

Correction, per Daniel Fischer's nice example:

$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^2} $$

the radius of convergence can be exactly $r=1$.

Note that $z f'(z) = - \log(1-z)$ by comparison with [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996974/is-log-1-z-sum-n-1-infty-fracznn-for-z-in-mathbbc-z), so both $f,f'$ have a singularity at $z=1$.

Nevertheless the power series coefficients $1/n^2$ are absolutely summable, so the polynomial truncations of the series converge uniformly to $f(z)$ on the unit disk.

Comment: No, bounded does not imply "no singularity". Consider $$f(z) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}.$$ The series converges uniformly on the closed unit disk, but the radius of convergence is $= 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer:  Thanks for correcting me!